# history.push does not work each and every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

I am making a ReactJS project, and in the login page, I've added the functionality that when a user signs is successfully, he is redirected automatically to the main page of the site. The authentication is through Firebase and this is the code

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
       .then(() => {
            console.log('Successfully signed in');
            this.setState({
                isLoading : false
            });
            this.props.history.push('/main');
       })
       .catch(err => {
           alert("There was some error signing in");
           console.log(err);
       })
```

However, the history.push does not work every time. Sometimes when I sign in, then it does redirect to the desired page but sometimes it does not.

Please tell what problem is happening and how do I fix it

Answer (score 0):

do you have some options here one of this is:

I asume you're using react-router-dom you can use hooks as this

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let history = useHistory();

auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
       .then(() => {
            console.log('Successfully signed in');
            this.setState({
                isLoading : false
            });
            history.push('/main');
       })
       .catch(err => {
           alert("There was some error signing in");
           console.log(err);
       })
```

one more go to your class component or functional component, in the export put this just if you're using react-router

````
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

.
.
.

export default withRouter(YourClassComponent); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same issue while using mongodb for my backend side. Sometimes I could see the updated values after history push but sometimes didnt. I solved this problem with using timeout value in my onSubmit method where I call the backend route.

```
setTimeout(() => {  history.push("/") }, 10);
```